# Как сделать самообновляемую службу Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows-service

На C# написана служба Windows. Нужно чтобы служба находила обновления, устанавливала их и перезапускалась.

Comment: И в чем вопрос?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, вопрос в том, есть ли готовые решения? Или городить свой велосипед?

Comment: насколько мне известно, не достаточно просто заменить файлы установленной службы на новые, да и система вполне может запретить это сделать. Так что вам понадобится отдельное приложение, которое (возможно по запросу самой службы) будет делать корректную деинсталляцию службы, обновление, установку и запуск

Comment: @rdorn, если служба запускается от имени локальной системы, у неё достаточно прав для управления службами.

Answer (score 0):

это делается парой апликух.
Одна апликуха -- и есть твоя апликуха/сервис.
Вторая - апдейтер.

Задача апдейтера -- запустится, проверить есть ли обновляшки на удаленном сервере. Потом работает ли твоя апликуха, если работает -- отключить. Сделать обновление и включить обратно(за условия если апликуха работала до этого!!!)

Включение и отключение автоапдейта достаточно прописать в таск скедлер операционной системы с нужным графиком.